# Hibernate Search RAMProvider - not sure how it works

Tags: spring, lucene, spring-boot, hibernate-search

I'm using spring boot and for easier setup(no user right manipulation) I decided to use RAM provider instead of FS. Can anyone confirm my way of thoughts.

- Whenever I'm restarting I'm loosing the index.
- Anytime something goes through Hibernate it will be auto-indexed as there are @Indexed annotations on proper entities.
- In case of restart I need to rebuild the index as it is lost using

```html
 try {
            FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =
                    Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(
                    "An error occurred trying to build the search index: " +
                            e.toString());
        }
```

- In case that I will use FSDirectoryProvider, index will be automatically reloaded from FS and above code is not necessary anymore. Unless, there is change in ORM entities. I guess then I will need somehow to manually force the re-indexing.

Is there some DBDirectory implementation that one can depend on? In this case the index file is loaded to RAM or each update to index is written to DB separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your assumptions are nearly correct.

An in-memory index is lost under two circumstances:

- JVM shutdown
- index gets reopened while application is still running

You need to reindex your entities only if:

- you changed the way how your entities are analyzed or tokenized during indexing or searching
- you added or removed entity properties from or to the index
- you changed relations between entities that affects your index

At the time of writting there is no database based directory. In the past I tried to adapt [Compass](http://www.compass-project.org/) [`JdbcDirectory`](http://www.compass-project.org/docs/2.2.0/api/org/apache/lucene/store/jdbc/JdbcDirectory.html). Unfortunately, I never had the time to go further than with a working proof of concept.

There is an open [issues](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-781) since 2011 in the project tracker. It seems that in near future there won't be official support for a database driven directory in Hibernate Search.

Keep in mind that an in-memory index is only sufficient for [small data](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/store/RAMDirectory.html):

> Warning: This class is not intended to work with huge indexes.
>   Everything beyond several hundred megabytes will waste resources (GC
>   cycles), because it uses an internal buffer size of 1024 bytes,
>   producing millions of byte[1024] arrays. This class is optimized for
>   small memory-resident indexes. It also has bad concurrency on
>   multithreaded environments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Infinispan Directory as an alternative to keep stuff in memory but have a replica on durable storage.

The Infinispan project provides both a

- an Apache Lucene Directory implementation
- an Hibernate Search DirectoryProvider

[A pointer to the source code](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/tree/master/lucene)

Infinispan is meant to aggressively cache data in memory, but has several options to offload such data to permanent storage by enabling a CacheStore in its configuration.

Among the many CacheStore implementations, you might be interested in:

- the [FSCacheStore which stores stuff in filesystem](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_filesystem_based_cache_stores)
- the [JDBC based CacheStore](http://infinispan.org/docs/8.2.x/user_guide/user_guide.html#_jdbc_based_cache_loaders) is often a good combo for Hibernate.

There are many more alternatives, like connecting to cloud storage, popular NoSQL databases, etc.. Infinispan also supports real-time replication across nodes, so your options for index storage in Hibernate Search are pretty much limitless.